# Unsigned 32 bit integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, integer, unsigned-integer

How can I emulate 32bit unsiged integers without any external dependencies in Javascript? Tricks with `x >>> 0` or `x | 0` don't work (for multiplication, they seem to work for addition / subtraction), and doubles lose precision during multiplication.

For example, try to multiply 2654435769 * 340573321 (mod 2^32). The result should be 1.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422061/1113426) has multiplication. What about addition / subtraction / division?

[Here's a link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mod%5B2654435769+*+340573321%2C+2%5E32%5D) to wolfram alpha, presenting the equation above.

Comment: But the result of `2654435769 * 340573321` does not fit in 32-bits...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: But mod 2^32 it does; that's what he's after with the computations if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: @pimvdb: yes, that's how 32bit unsigned integers work -- all operations are performed modulo 2^32.

Comment: I see. I'm surprised that doubles lose precision like this, I had no idea.

Comment: that might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32-bit unsigned int fits within Javascript's [64-bit float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) -- there should be no loss of precision when performing addition, subtraction, or division.  Just mask with `0xffffffff` to stay within a 32-bit integer.  Multiplication goes beyond what fits, but you already have a solution for that.

Comment: However the precision may not be high enough after the multiplication, because to 32-bit integers multiplied can get a 64-bit integer, while the 64-bit floating number can only represent 53 significant bits. Is there a better way?

Comment: Beware there are still some terrible pitfalls like `(1 << 31).toString(16) === '-80000000'` (note sign). This is because [The left operand will be converted to a 32-bit integer, which means floating point numbers will be truncated, and number not within the 32-bit bounds will over-/underflow.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift)
To work around that, use multiplication instead of shift, e.g. `(0x8000 * 65536)` instead of `(0x8000 << 16)`

Answer (score 1):

You can ape it with BigInts in 2020.

```js
const u32mul = (x, y) => Number((BigInt(x) * BigInt(y)) & 0xFFFFFFFFn);
```

A sufficiently smart compiler should work this out, but I haven't benchmarked this, so proceed with caution.

The other alternative would of course drop into WebAssembly. If you need to be working at this level, I'd *strongly* advise it.