# How do I emulate x86 unsigned 32-bit integer multiplication using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, x86, unsigned, emulation, emscripten

Compiling this code using Emscripten:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
unsigned long d1 = 0x847c9b5d;
unsigned long q =  0x549530e1;
printf("%lu\n", d1*q);
return 0;
}
```

yields (using `-g`):

```
  $d1=-2072208547; //@line 3 "minusmul.c"
  $q=1419063521; //@line 4 "minusmul.c"
  var $2=$d1; //@line 5 "minusmul.c"
  var $3=$q; //@line 5 "minusmul.c"
  var $4=((($2)*($3))|0); //@line 5 "minusmul.c"
```

Executing this using `js` (SpiderMonkey I believe?) or `node`, I get the result `3217488896`. Executing the native executable (compiled using GCC), I get `3217489085`. How would one emulate the x86 unsigned 32-bit integer multiplication using JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232939/is-there-a-way-to-correctly-multiply-two-32-bit-integers-in-javascript/6422061

Comment: I posted an answer on the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232939/is-there-a-way-to-correctly-multiply-two-32-bit-integers-in-javascript/6422061).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emscripten either does not support exact 32-bit multiplication or it is a bug. Since they mention on the homepage that they have software emulation for 64-bit math, I think it's a bug. I discovered that you can use CHECK_OVERFLOWS and it will discover the overflow. It doesn't seem to "repair" it though. To make the program finish with CHECK_OVERFLOWS you need to up the count, marked by "XXX" in the generated source.

Comment: ok turns out it was a bug. [fix here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/commit/c14a675125a6d94d80561e986549280eee5e958d), [issue here](https://github.com/kripken/gmp.js/issues/2)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses the [IEEE-754](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) standard ([see also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) as its internal number representation. This is floating-point arithmetic, so you're going to have to come up with your own library functions to emulate bitwise arithmetic for large integers. Several libraries exist, such as [BigInt](http://leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html) and [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).

Comment: Single precision floats can represent all numbers between 0 and 2^32-1 AFAIK, so I don't see what I need BigInts for.

Comment: There are a lot of discussions on this topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t